# Magento MySQL query multi left join - error in syntax

Tags: mysql, magento, left-join

So, Magento has an EAV table structure which makes writing queries very interesting. I am attempting to pull a few rows of data related to a unique customer matched up against another table that has additional data about the customer.

In order to do this, I am currently attempting to LEFT JOIN five tables in one query and build a result set for the individual customer.

Here is the table structure:

Customer Entity Table

```
customer_entity_varchar

+----+------------+--------------+----------+
| id | entity_id  | attribute_id |   value  |
+----+------------+--------------+----------+
|  2 | 1          | 100          | Bob Doe  |
|  3 | 1          | 101          | James    |
|  5 | 1          | 102          | Thompson |
|  7 | 2          | 100          | Bob Doe  |
|  9 | 2          | 101          | Mary     |
+----+------------+--------------+----------+
```

Customer Pricing Table

```
pricesystem_customerprice

+----+------------+--------------+----------+-------+------------+
| id | entity_id  |  customer_id |   value  |  qty  |     to     |
+----+------------+--------------+----------+-------+------------+
|  2 | 35         | 1            | 34.99    |  10   | 2014-06-18 |
|  3 | 3495       | 2            | 123.99   |  5    | 2014-06-18 |
+----+------------+--------------+----------+-------+------------+
```

Catalog Products Table

```
catalog_product_entity

+----+------------+----------------+
| id | entity_id  |       sku      |
+----+------------+----------------+
|  2 | 35         | Fenix-E01-Blue |
|  3 | 3495       | Sunwayman-V11R |
+----+------------+----------------+
```

My query is below:

```
SELECT 
    t1.`value` as account_manager, 
    t2.`value` as lastname, 
    t3.`value` as firstname,
    s.sku as item,
    c.`value` as price,
    c.qty as quantity,
    c.`comment` as `comment`
FROM 
    customer_entity_varchar as t1 
        on c.customer_id = t1.entity_id AND t1.attribute_id = 286
left join 
    customer_entity_varchar as t2
        on c.customer_id = t2.entity_id AND t2.attribute_id = 5
left join
    customer_entity_varchar as t3 
        on c.customer_id = t3.entity_id AND t3.attribute_id = 7 
left join 
    pricesystem_customerprice as c 
        on c.customer_id = t2.entity_id
left join 
    catalog_product_entity as s 
        on s.entity_id = c.entity_id 
WHERE c.`to` = '2014-06-18'
```

There appears to be something wrong with the syntax, however I am not too well versed in joining tables, so I may have typed something wrong. I did put in some research on this, and got it as far as I have.

If I drop out the need to get the customers first and last name, then I can make the statement work joining the two tables.

Here is the desired result set:

```
Array (
0 => array (
    account_manager => Bob Doe,
    firstname => James,
    lastname => Thompson,
    item => Fenix-E01-Blue,
    price => 34.99,
    quantity => 10),
1 => array (
    account_manager => Bob Doe,
    firstname => Mary,
    lastname => Thompson,
    item => Sunwayman-V11R,
    price => 123.99,
    quantity => 5)
)
```

Let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your joins are slightly out of order, what you need is to choose a base table as origin (here I chose the product table) and left join everything to that;

```
SELECT 
    t1.`value` as account_manager, 
    t2.`value` as lastname, 
    t3.`value` as firstname,
    s.sku as item,
    c.`value` as price,
    c.qty as quantity
FROM pricesystem_customerprice as c 
LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar as t1 
  ON c.customer_id = t1.entity_id AND t1.attribute_id = 100
LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar as t2
  ON c.customer_id = t2.entity_id AND t2.attribute_id = 101
LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar as t3 
  ON c.customer_id = t3.entity_id AND t3.attribute_id = 102
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity as s 
  ON s.entity_id = c.entity_id 
WHERE c.`to` = '2014-06-18'
```

Also, your conditions on each join should only reference tables that have already been joined before the current join, not tables listed in joins below the current one.

[A simple SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0365d/1).